# Java: array index out of bounds. Looping problems

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to java but, I'm making an encryption program that places each character in a grid. In this case I'll just be using "abcde" as my string. When put through the program, it's supposed to place each character in a 3x2 (height x width) grid. The program reads the grid from top to bottom then moving on to the next row and it'll be read as, "acebd." This part of the program is loading each character into char [height][width].

```
line length: 5, height: 3, width: 2, longColumn: 1
//longColumn -- the number of valid columns in the last row


static char[][] loadGrid(String line, int width, int height, int longColumn) {
  char grid[][] = new char[height][width];


  int charCount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= line.length()-1; i++){
     if (i < line.length()-1) {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {   
           for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
              if (r < height - 1 || c < longColumn) {
                 grid[r][c] = line.charAt(charCount);
                 charCount += 1;
              }
           }
        }
     } 
  }
return grid;  
}
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at GridEncrypt.loadGrid(GridEncrypt.java:93)
at GridEncrypt.processInput(GridEncrypt.java:65)
at GridEncrypt.main(GridEncrypt.java:19)
```

To my understanding the charCount isn't going to 4, just staying at 3. I've tired messing around with it but it either just stays at 3 or goes to 5. Also, I'm thinking that it goes through the first two for loops once and then just doesn't go back to it after it runs through the 3rd loop. Which then the 3rd loop is the only one that's being looped properly. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is height and what is width? Why aren't you using `grid.length`?

Comment: Height is r, which is 3. Width is c, and that's 2. Grid isn't anything yet, just an empty array. Basically, line.length is the number of times I want it to be looped, dependent on how many characters there are in the string. @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point of `longColumn`, and I think you wanted something like

```
static char[][] loadGrid(String line, int width, int height) {
    char grid[][] = new char[height][width];
    int charCount = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            if (charCount < line.length()) {
                grid[r][c] = line.charAt(charCount);
                charCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the debugger, and stepping through the program. Make sure to keep track of array sizes and variables (especially r and c). The error is being caused by (r,c) being outside the array. Also, a few other things.

1.`charcount += 1;` can be replaced with `charcount++;`
2. Remember that when dealing with integers, `if (r < height - 1)` is essentially the same as `if(r <= height - 2)`
3. The variables i and charcount are saying the same thing anyways, so you can combine those variables.